# Can I use these sentences interchangeably?

Tags: comparison

1. Usually happy and sometimes sad people tend to be friendly.
2. Happy and sad people tend to be friendly. (Does it only mean people who are happy and sad at the same time, not who are usually happy and sometimes sad? I want this sentence but I wish it wouldn't mean 'at the same time')

I mean people who are usually happy but who are sometimes sad tend to be friendly (because some sadness makes people sympathetic so friendly).

I think people use sentence 2 like 'people happy and sad at the same time tend to be friendly' but can sentence 2 be technically used as sentence 1?

Comment: I would say it's quite unusual for people to be both happy and sad at the same time, and neither of these sentences necessarily imply that. For this reason, I would suggest that if you want to be so specific, then you would really have to spell it out and say exactly what you mean: e.g., "People who are sad and happy at the same time tend to be friendly".

Answer (score 1):

"Those people who are usually happy, but sometimes sad, tend to be friendly."

Your second version could imply that you are referring to two different kinds of people.

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences need life support.

Try this:

> Happy people tend to be friendly, but sometimes sad people are
> friendly too.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm looking for.